# How to set imageView in circle like imageContacts in Swift correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, xcode6

I want to show a picture into imageView like the image contact (in a circle) But when I try to show this, the imageView rescale his size and this doesn't show correctly in a circle.

```
 image.layer.borderWidth=1.0
 image.layer.masksToBounds = false
 image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
 image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height/2
 image.clipsToBounds = true
```

I want to show like this: 
[image]

But I get this:
[image]

How can do the image resize to UIImageView size to show as a circle?

Thanks!

Comment: here is solution for case the imageview had Width different with Height: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685055/ios-frame-size-width-2-doesnt-produce-a-circle-on-every-device

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What `frame` size are you using for `image`? I can get a perfect circle if I set the frame to be a square.

```
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
```

Comment: my image size in the size inspector is set to 120 width and 120 height, yet when I run it, it's not a perfect circle because the width turns out to be a bit longer? Why?

Comment: If the frame is a square, setting the radius to half the width/height will always give you a circular view. If one is creating a custom class that might accomadate various squared frame sizes, one mustn't hardcode the radius value.

Comment: This is actually the only correct answer, if you don't set your imageView to square none of other answers will work.

Comment: "'CGRectMake' is unavailable in Swift".

Answer (score 57):

This is solution which I have used in my app:

```
var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width/2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Swift 4.0

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width / 2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Why all answers here so up-voted so much? isn't it a bit stupid to use cornerRadius there is image don't have to be square?

Comment: "Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'frame'". Hmmmm.

Answer (score 21):

***Fast*** and ***Simple*** solution.

How to **mask** `UIImage` to Circle without cropping with Swift.

```
extension UIImageView {
  public func maskCircle(anyImage: UIImage) {
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.clipsToBounds = true

   // make square(* must to make circle), 
   // resize(reduce the kilobyte) and 
   // fix rotation.
   self.image = anyImage
  }
}
```

How to call:

```
let anyAvatarImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "avatar")!
avatarImageView.maskCircle(anyAvatarImage)
```

Comment: I cannot find `prepareImage()` method. Has it been changed?

Comment: @Antonio that is his custom func... you just use    self.image = anyImage

Comment: I removed extra function. Thank you @BorisNikolić

Answer (score 11):

Try this it's work for me ,

set **imageView** width and height same .

**Swift**

```
imageview?.layer.cornerRadius = (imageview?.frame.size.width ?? 0.0) / 2     
imageview?.clipsToBounds = true
imageview?.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
imageview?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Objective C**

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

Hope this will help to some one .

Answer (score 9):

Create your custom circle UIImageView and create the circle under the layoutSubviews helps if you use Autolayout.

```
/*
      +-------------+
      |             |
      |             |
      |             |
      |             |
      |             |
      |             |
      +-------------+
  The IMAGE MUST BE SQUARE
*/
class roundImageView: UIImageView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // 1. setup any properties here
        // 2. call super.init(frame:)
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // 1. setup any properties here
        // 2. call super.init(coder:)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest making your image file a perfect square to begin with. This can be done in almost any photo editing program. After that, this should work within viewDidLoad. Credit to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue3fQgDkNdk)

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.width/2
image.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 7):

That is all you need....

```
        profilepic = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width * 0.19 , self.view.bounds.height * 0.1))
        profilepic.layer.borderWidth = 1
        profilepic.layer.masksToBounds = false
        profilepic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        profilepic.layer.cornerRadius = profilepic.frame.height/2
        profilepic.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Do you need to import ```quartzcore``` for this?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff nope.!

Answer (score 5):

If your using a `UIViewController` here's how do do it using **Anchors**. The key is to set the imageView's `layer.cornerRadius` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` like so:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
}
```

Also make sure the `heightAnchor` and `widthAnchor` are the same size. They are both `100` in my example below

Code:

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    return imageView
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pizzaImage")
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
}
```

If your using a `CollectionView Cell` set the imageView's `layer.cornerRadius` in `layoutSubviews()`:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "pizzaImage")

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews() // call super.layoutSubviews()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
}
```

Comment: adding the corner radius code to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` worked for me to make my ImageView a perfect circle

Comment: adding corner radius to viewWillLayoutSubviews when imageview is anchor through the storyboard worked for me for all devices, I had an issue when it worked for iPhone X or greater but did not work for iPhone 8.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

this extension really works for me (including in swift 4+)

```
extension UIImageView {
    func roundedImage() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = (self.frame.size.width) / 2;
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}
```

Then simply call it as

```
imageView.roundedImage()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
reviewerImage.layer.cornerRadius = reviewerImage.frame.size.width / 2;
reviewerImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

what i found out is that your width and height of image view must return an even number when divided by 2 to get a perfect circle e.g

```
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120))
```

it should not be something like
    let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 130))

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar result (more of an oval than a circle). It turned out that the constraints I set on the `UIImageView` forced it into an oval instead of a circle. After fixing that, the above solutions worked.

Answer (score 2):

try this.
**swift** code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    perform(#selector(self.setCircleForImage(_:)), with: pickedImage, afterDelay: 0)
}


 @objc func setCircleForImage(_ imageView : UIImageView){
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = pickedImage.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it doing modifying the view:

1. Go to your *Main.storyboard*
2. Click on your image
3. View -> Mode -> Aspect Fill

**It works perfectly**

Answer (score 1):

This work perfectly for me.
The order of lines is **important**

```
func circularImage(photoImageView: UIImageView?)
{
    photoImageView!.layer.frame = CGRectInset(photoImageView!.layer.frame, 0, 0)
    photoImageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    photoImageView!.layer.cornerRadius = photoImageView!.frame.height/2
    photoImageView!.layer.masksToBounds = false
    photoImageView!.clipsToBounds = true
    photoImageView!.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    photoImageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
}
```

How to use:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    ...
    ...
    circularImage(photoImageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works for me. For perfect circle result, use the same size for width and height. like `image.frame = CGRect(0,0,200, 200)`

For non perfect circle, width and height should not be equal like this codes below.

```
 image.frame = CGRect(0,0,200, 160)
 image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
 image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height/2
 image.layer.masksToBounds = false
 image.layer.clipsToBounds = true
 image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to make image round

```
     self.layoutIfNeeded()
     self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 
     self.imageView.frame.width/2
     self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the **height** and **width** should be the **same** as your image/view.

1. Like an image with 100 widths and 100 height sizes (100 X 100). If the sizes are different then the circle does not look like a circle.

Answer (score 1):

```
// MARK: ImageView extension to make rounded   
@IBDesignable extension UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var masksToBounds: Bool {
        set {
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.masksToBounds
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            guard let uiColor = newValue else { return }
            layer.borderColor = uiColor.cgColor
        }
        get {
            guard let color = layer.borderColor else { return nil }
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this file extension to your project & Don't forget to make your image **Square** "Width = Height" and you can grantee it by giving the image width and **Aspect Ratio (1:1)**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
    
}
```

Then you will write this **line** in the cell or view controller or wherever you use your image:

```
imageViewCountryImage.cornerRadius = imageViewCountryImage.frame.height / 2
```

and you will find your image very super circular

Answer (score 0):

You can add this extension to your code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
            return color
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Just add this extension***

***Extension:***

```
extension UIImageView { 

    func circleImageView() {
       layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
       layer.borderWidth = 2
       contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
       layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
       layer.masksToBounds = false
       clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
self.imageView?.circleImageView()
```

One more thing, in order to make the image circle we've to set both width and height equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your height and width of your `UIImageView` is equal, or else it will look elliptical.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with using these codes

```
private let profileAvatarImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width/2
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "person")
        imageView.backgroundColor = .black
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return imageView
    }()
```