# iOS: frame.size.width/2 doesn't produce a circle on every device

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm aware that the formulae `frame.size.width/2` should produce a circle border, however in XCode I am currently experiencing some discrepancies.

I have two test devices (iPhone6 and 5th gen iPod touch) I also have the simulator running.  Both my devices display correctly but the simulator draws my circle as a rounded rectangle:

[image]

The code I am using to achieve this (although very simple) is:

```
imgAvatar.layer.masksToBounds = true
imgAvatar.clipsToBounds = true
imgAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = imgAvatar.frame.size.width/2
imgAvatar.layer.borderWidth = 5
imgAvatar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Is there any reason why this is happening? It's driving me insane!

**UPDATE** To clear confusion, the `UIImageView` is declared in my storyboard as `190x190` it also has a `1:1` aspect ratio constraint applied to it to ensure it maintains a proportional width and height.

**UPDATE 2** To put any suspicions regarding my auto-layout constraints to bed, I have attached the below image which shows the constraints set for `imgAvatar`. As you can see a the width and height match and the AR is set to ensure it maintains that 1:1 ratio.   I hope that clears up any further doubts

[image]

**ANSWER** Leo pointed out an extremely practical and reusable solution to fix this problem, using Swift extensions one can ensure that a given UIImage is always square, thus always generating a circle, I have posted Leo's solution below:

```
extension UIImage {
    var circleMask: UIImage? {
        let square = CGSize(width: min(size.width, size.height), height: min(size.width, size.height))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .init(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = self
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        imageView.layer.render(in: context)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}

imgAvatar.image = yourImage.circleMask
```

Comment: Can you try logging the `imgFrame`, as well as the resulting `cornerRadius` property? (Note that `NSStringFromCGRect()` might be helpful here.)

Comment: Where is this code (in what method)?

Comment: It's in a method called `initFrames` which is called in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: That's the problem. `viewDidLoad` is too soon. The view controller's view isn't sized yet. Try `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Moved to `viewWillAppear` seeing the same results

Comment: Do you check if your frame is square (4 equals sides) ?

Comment: Do you try comment masksToBounds and clipsToBounds?

Comment: Is the shape incorrect on the other simulators, or only on the iPhone 6 one?

Comment: Only in the simulators, not on either iPhone or iPod

Comment: It whould be in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Can you move your code to viewDidLayoutSubviews and share the result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create an extension to apply the mask and border straight to your image so it will always work disregarding the screen size / scale:

edit/update:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5 or later**

```
extension UIImage {
    var circleMask: UIImage? {
        let square = CGSize(width: min(size.width, size.height), height: min(size.width, size.height))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .init(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = self
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        imageView.layer.render(in: context)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

---

```
imgAvatar.image = yourImage.circleMask
```

Comment: Wow I love this solution, my first exposure to extensions and this is perfect. Thank you so much Leonardo!

Comment: Yes that is what i meant by subclassing :). Anyway good answer!

Comment: I am using a collection view with nearly 30 items. My collection view performs laggy with this solution. can you think of a more efficient solution in this case?

Answer (score 8):

Well, Autolayout should be the issue. As it can be seen the height of the `imgAvatar` on **right is greater than** the height of the `imgAvatar` on **left**.

The size of `imgAvatar` on right is **190 x 190** and the one on left is **200 x 200**, but on the left the corner radius which you are setting is **190/2** i.e. **95px** whereas it should be **100px**.

Kindly set **Height** & **Width** Constraint in your nib file for `imgAvatar`, if you do not want the **imgAvatar** to resize by 1:1.

1. Select imgAvatar in your nib.
2. Editor > Pin > Height
3. Select imgAvatar in your nib.
4. Editor > Pin > Width

**OR**

Try moving your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

**OR**

Subclass your `UIImageView` and set its corner radius in its `awakeFromNib` method

Kindly let us know if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you had already mentioned about your 1:1 ratio. So either keep it fixed and dont resize, or move your code to viewDidLayoutSubviews. Because what happens is you set the corner radius as 95px but autolayout resizes the image according to 1:1 ratio and you are setting it before the view has been resized.

Comment: I see, that makes total sense - this solution also worked for me when moving code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. - Upvoted, but accepting Leonardos answer as its nice for a failsafe solution

Comment: I like your answer because you explained *why* the issue was occurring.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you test in iOS8.3, you should call `layoutIfNeed` on your UI object before get its frame. Please read [iOS8.3 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.3/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015151)

For example:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
// code that sets up the button, but doesn’t yet add it to a window
CGRect titleFrame = button.titleLabel.frame;
// code that relies on the correct value for titleFrame
```

You now need:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
// code that sets up the button, but doesn’t yet add it to a window
[button layoutIfNeeded]; // This is also safe pre-iOS 8.3
CGRect titleFrame = button.titleLabel.frame;
// code that relies on the correct value for titleFrame
```

It's said that for UIButton and sub-classes but you can try it also with your UI object.

> When linking against iOS 8.3, any code that relies on layout
>   information (such as the frame) of a UIButton subview when the button
>   is not in the window hierarchy will need to send layoutIfNeeded to the
>   button before retrieving layout information (such as
>   button.titleLabel.frame) to ensure that the layout values are up to
>   date.

Also, as the imgAvatar's cornerRadius was set to 1/2 of imgFrame's size, you will get a circle only if that cornerRadius value = 1/2 of imgAvatar's width (and height).

So, after the call:

```
imgAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = imgFrame.frame.size.width/2
```

verify :

- frame size of imgAvatar and its cornerRadius
- be sure that image is squared

Comment: Even calling `layoutIfNeeded()` does not remedy this problem...very strange - thankyou for the suggestion though! :)

Comment: what is the value of imgFrame's frame? It seems that your imgAvatar is bigger than imgView, that why when you use 1/2 size of your imgView, the imgAvatar with that value of corner radius does not produce a circle.

Comment: its `(origin = (x = 205, y = 106), size = (width = 190, height = 190)) `

Comment: It's the same size, I checked in the storyboard too.  If it wasn't the same size then it wouldn't produce a circle on one environment and a rectangle in another?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when the circle is applied, the bounds of the view are **still considered the default (320x480)** and so if you have set constraints related to the screen, the image will be bigger on iPhone 6/6+ for instance.

There are various solution, but if you want a fast one, just put your code:

```
imgAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = imgFrame.frame.size.width/2
```

in `- viewDidLayoutSubviews` in your view controller or in `- layoutSubviews` in your view, **checking before if the cornerRadius is different from the width/2 of the image's frame**. Something like this:

```
if (imgAvatar.layer.cornerRadius != imgFrame.frame.size.width/2) {
    imgAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = imgFrame.frame.size.width/2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula you used will only work for squared image. Are you using auto lay out? Maybe it could be stretched for the device that you used. If this is the case, then height will be higher than width,or vice versa. That is, the image will be some kind of rectangle, and it will not produce perfect circle.

Comment: I am applying the formula to the UIImageView and not the UIImage, the UIImageView is a 190x190 square, I applied 1:1 Aspect ratio constraints and width/height=190.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @leo Dabus for the original solution 
Following is just an update for swift 4.2

```
import UIKit
extension UIImage {
    var circleMask: UIImage {
        let square = size.width < size.height ? CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.width) : CGSize(width: size.height, height: size.height)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
        imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        imageView.image = self
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        imageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result!
    }
}
```