# Make images round in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to make images circular and for some reason the below code is creating a diamond-shaped photo:

```
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2
    profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
```

How do I make it round? Thanks!

Comment: code is perfect, just set the constraint of your view perfectly so the width of profilepicture will be found by compiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29685559/2303865

Comment: @Kody R., you can accept the answer if its worked for you. :)

Comment: @AshishKakkad I apologize if this sounds silly, I'm quite new to all of this! What do you mean by setting the constraint "perfectly"? I have constraints, I'm just not certain what you mean by perfect.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's great! Thank you for the extension to make it a bit easier

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866768/circle-collectionview-image-according-to-device-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's displaying a diamond shape because you're setting the cornerRadius before the the size of the view changes.

This would result in a diamond shape:

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
view.addSubview(myView)
myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width / 2
// setting frame doesn't change corner radius from the former large value
myView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
```

You can set this immediately before the view is displayed by doing so in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: That was it! I had it in viewDidAppear, so your comment makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing something, below code works for me:

```
            profilePicture.layer.borderWidth=1.0
            profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = false
            profilePicture.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.frame.size.height/2
            profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
```

Note: To get a perfect circle, the image view frame should be square.

Answer (score 0):

To get any `UIImageview` in circular shape , you need to first set it's Frame to square shape . For example , if you `UIImageView` has Frame`(20,20,100,100)` see the height and width are the same. Then you need to set the `cornerradius` propety of that `UIImageview` to **half** the size of its **height** or **width** .

I did something like this in Xamarin.iOS:-

```
 imageView.Layer.CornerRadius = imageView.Frame.Size.Width / 2;
 imageView.ClipsToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out it worked for me, i just added a self. before the commands

```
    self.profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true;
```

hope it works :)