# circle collectionview image according to device size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, geometry

Hello in my horizontal collectionview i want to circle image , if i set static height and width it works but it does not work if i set constraint 
iam using this method to circle my image

```
    public static func circularImageWhite(photoImageView: UIImageView?)
{
    photoImageView!.layer.frame = photoImageView!.layer.frame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    photoImageView!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    photoImageView!.layer.cornerRadius = photoImageView!.frame.height/2
    photoImageView!.layer.masksToBounds = false
    photoImageView!.clipsToBounds = true
    photoImageView!.layer.borderWidth = 1
    photoImageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
}
```

i want to circle image on every device

Comment: You can get circle visualization of any control only if the height and width of that control is same.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla I don't think so mate. If you think so then please share any example of code in which the height and width of control is not same and you are getting circular visual.

Comment: @Rameez, just setting the radius of the mask to min(width, height)/2 https://github.com/galots/CircleButton

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla here we were talking about layer's corner radius property. You can also see the above question. In your example you have to do a lot of work to get circular view and lot of static values. That's fine for specific situation. But in general and in the case of Auto Layout, we must have to use Layer's corner radius property to save many lines of code. And that can happens only if height and width of control is same.

Answer (score 1):

Everything about your code is wrong.

```
photoImageView!.layer.frame = photoImageView!.layer.frame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

That line is meaningless. If you inset the frame by zero you are not changing it. So that line does nothing at all.

```
photoImageView!.layer.masksToBounds = false
photoImageView!.clipsToBounds = true
```

A layer's `masksToBounds` and a view's `clipsToBounds` are actually the very same property. So you are setting the same property to `false` and then back to `true` in the very next line. Thus the first of those two lines does nothing at all.

```
photoImageView!.layer.cornerRadius = photoImageView!.frame.height/2
```

That is actually the heart of the matter. The problem is that you are setting the corner radius according to the frame height. But that assumes you know what the frame is. You don't. As you yourself said, this doesn't work if you set autolayout constraints on your view. Why? Because of the order in which things happen:

1. First, you use the current frame height to set the corner radius.
2. Then, the constraints kick in and change the frame. So now the corner radius that you set before doesn't "fit" the image view any more.

Moreover, setting the corner radius is a lousy way to clip a view to a circle. The correct way is to *mask* the view to an actual circle.

So, to sum up: You should use a UIImageView subclass that overrides its own `layoutSubviews` to set its own mask to a circle that fits the current size. As the size changes due to constraints, `layoutSubviews` will be called and your code will change the mask to fit properly.

(The white circular border can be yet another layer or subview that draws the circle.)

The matter comes up quite often, and I often see the `cornerRadius` misused in this same way, so here's an actual implementation:

```
class CircleImageView : UIImageView {
     override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.sublayers = nil
        let radius = min(self.bounds.height, self.bounds.width)/2
        let cen = CGPoint(x:self.bounds.width/2, y:self.bounds.height/2)
        let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:self.bounds.size)
        var im : UIImage?
        var outline : UIImage?
        r.image { ctx in
            let con = ctx.cgContext
            UIColor.black.setFill()
            con.addArc(center: cen, radius: radius, 
                startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi*2, clockwise: true)
            let p = con.path
            con.fillPath()
            im = ctx.currentImage
            con.clear(CGRect(origin:.zero, size:self.bounds.size))
            con.addPath(p!)
            UIColor.clear.setFill()
            UIColor.white.setStroke() // border color, change as desired
            con.setLineWidth(4) // border width, change as desired
            con.strokePath()
            outline = ctx.currentImage
        }
        // the circle mask
        let iv = UIImageView(image:im)
        iv.contentMode = .center
        iv.frame = self.bounds
        self.mask = iv
        // the border
        let iv2 = UIImageView(image:outline)
        iv2.contentMode = .center
        iv2.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(iv2)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Use CircleImageView as your image view and you'll get the right result. I repeat: the important thing is that this will continue to work no matter how the CircleImageView itself is subsequently resized.