# How do I properly crop a photo for profile picture?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, crop

I am allowing users to select their profile picture, but when I import it and cut the borders and make it round, it looks very weird. Is there a proper way to do this?

```
propic.layer.borderWidth = 2
propic.layer.masksToBounds = false
propic.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("ffffff").CGColor
propic.layer.cornerRadius = propic.frame.height/2
propic.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Define "it looks very weird" (posting a screenshot would be good). Is your view a square? Also `masksToBounds` and `clipsToBounds` are the one and same property, so you don't need to set `masksToBounds` to `false`.

Comment: The square picture looks normal, but when converted to the circular picture it "squishes" the persons face, so now their face is like a toothpick.

Comment: you can find all here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29685559/1894067

Comment: Try to change the content mode to Aspect Fill.

Comment: Do you just want to mask away the parts outside the circle for display, or do you want to create a cropped version of the image where the pixels outside the circle are forced to transparent or black? Those are 2 different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
propic.layer.borderWidth = 2
propic.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("ffffff").CGColor
propic.layer.cornerRadius = propic.frame.height/2
propic.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: And comment out the line of propic.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: its already suggested in comments above. I think imageView frame is not coming right.