# rounded imageView 's border is not smooth after setting image property

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

```
class PPAvatarCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var imageView:UIImageView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0, 0), size: CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)))

    self.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 10
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "demo")
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width*0.5
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

the border is smooth and great with above code 
but after  add    `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "demo")`

the imageView's border is no longer smooth.
Why did this happen ?

[image: smooth image]

[image: not smooth image]

---

UPDATE:

Seems something wrong with layer.radius ,the border is smooth even with image property set on imageView after remove    `imageView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width*0.5`

[image]

---

UPDATE 2:
turn out to be something wrong with UICollectionViewCell , imageView is a part of UICollectionViewCell

---

Comment: are you capture this from device?? can you check in real Device ?? that might be happen because of your monitor screen resolution.

Comment: @NitinGohel same on device

Comment: Have you tried changing cornerRadius value?

Comment: @Kiran I set radius to be constant 17 , the result turns out to be same

Comment: can someone upvote the question?@NitinGohel @Kiran

Comment: You can benefit from these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046571/cut-a-uiimage-into-a-circle-swiftios

Comment: @fatihyildizhan cut a image to round ,for my case , is unnecessary and would cause performance issue.

Comment: Maybe you should look over Haneke and AlamofireImage or https://github.com/gavinbunney/Toucan , they could solve your problem.

Comment: @fatihyildizhan the repo is awesome though , i'm not gonna clip my image.

Answer (score 0):

u can use 2 imageview 1 to show image and second to hide and show circular image.

1st imageview show image as it is.

2nd imageview which will have white background and green circle above 1st image and middle of image will be transparent

[image: like this]

Comment: I know,but very curious about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your image should be a square. Than do these:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.image = "yourSquareImage"
```

Check the full solution with ***easy using*** **extension**:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36102901/2125010

Comment: your solution is not working . your code is same as mine . you can please try a collection view cell demo