# how to setImage in UIButton in Round shape ,select photo using ImagePickerView

Tags: swift

How to `setImage` in `UIButton` in Round shape ,select photo using ImagePickerView

[image]

Comment: Hi Kathir, and welcome to SO. If you take a little tour of the questions asked and well answered here, you'll see it is better to post the parts of the code you think must be improved.  You must show at least some research efforts. Read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set imageView in circle like imageContacts in Swift correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587713/how-to-set-imageview-in-circle-like-imagecontacts-in-swift-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Write like,

```
    self.btn.frame = CGRectMake(70, 300, 100, 100)
    self.btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ImageName"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)  // Assign your selected image from imagePicker
    self.btn.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.btn.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.btn.layer.cornerRadius = self.btn.frame.height/2
    self.btn.clipsToBounds = true
```

Its working fine.

Comment: How to set image in round button using  UIImagePicker as circle shape

Comment: @KathirShankeerth have you got it?