# Image in circle not working in iPhone 5 (works in iPhone 7)

Tags: swift, uiimageview

In my iPhone 7 simulator, my image is an exact circle. For some reason my image in iPhone 5 becomes a little squarish. This is the code that I have to make the image a circle:

```
    private func setImage(){
    self.profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImage.frame.size.height/2;
    self.profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

There is a 1:1 aspect ratio constraint on the image. Also it works on iPhone 7 perfectly

And I add an image to show the problem in the result in iPhone 5.

[image]

Comment: before setting corner radius print image frame , height and width should be same if you want proper circle.

Comment: (134.0, 22.0, 107.0, 107.0)
This is the frame

Comment: Its not possible , somewhere your image frame is changing and cause this. Only one reason could be is different height and width.

Comment: Please see my answer. The problem was that this Frame that I added was Iphone 7's frame for that image, so the height and weight were equal but it wasn't the correct frame to use for this setup.

Comment: Where you are calling this method? It happened with me also. Ratio not work properly. Use view hierarchy and see it property. Follow this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150186/how-do-i-inspect-the-view-hierarchy-in-ios

Comment: I solved the issue, you can see in my answer. The problem was that the frames did not yet update when I called the change (they were set to iphone 7, not to iphone 5. So adding layoutIfNeeded in the beginning of viewDidLoad made it work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set imageView in circle like imageContacts in Swift correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587713/how-to-set-imageview-in-circle-like-imagecontacts-in-swift-correctly)

Comment: Not a duplicate, since the problem was specifically in iphone 5, and the answer (that i eventually supplied), was different than what you have in the link you shared. Did you even read the answers?

Comment: Please do not put meta-commentary in the question (especially at the start where it doesn't make much sense) or add [solved] to the title. If you would like to put some of that material in your answer, please do - it can be found in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42368265/revisions).

Comment: Downvoted for not reading the above advice.

Comment: I seriously do not understand what is the problem. I asked a question, the suggested as duplicates did NOT solve my issue, my answer solved it so I marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Since in storyboard I am working in iphone 7, I have to add this command in my view did load, so the frame updates the constraints for iphone 5 before making the change:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I hope this helps people!

Answer (score 0):

Let call this function in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you should add

> ```
> self.profileImage.layoutIfNeeded()
> ```

before :

> self.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius =self.profileImage.frame.size.height/2