# How to get circle shaped image in swift 3

Tags: ios, image, swift3, geometry

From the below code I got only oval shaped image I don't know why and what I did wrong..?

```
   self.viewCirlce.layer.cornerRadius = self.viewCirlce.frame.size.width / 2
   self.viewCirlce.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Does your `viewCirlce ` height equal to width?

Comment: please do some google you will get similar question over stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587713/how-to-set-imageview-in-circle-like-imagecontacts-in-swift-correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the component you have called viewCirlce is a rectangle to start with, you are just setting the corner radius. If the component has the same width and height then this could give you a circle. If it's a rectangle, then you'll get an ellipse.

Comment: How could I change the viewCircle width and height

Comment: I have the same height and width for the viewCircle but the image displayed in oval shape....

Answer (score 5):

This code used to display the circle image

```
image.layer.borderWidth = 1
image.layer.masksToBounds = false
image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.height/2
image.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Otherwise put a your imageview  Height and Width are equal Size  like  let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    image.layer.borderWidth = 1
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.height/2
    image.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code and make sure your viewCirlce is a square view

```
 self.viewCirlce.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure height and width of viewCirlce are equal and put your this code in a method which is called after viewCirlce is loaded for e.g :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      self.viewCirlce =  self.viewCirlce.frame.size.height / 2.0
      self.viewCirlce.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: I have the same height and width for the viewCircle but the image displayed in oval shape....

Comment: i have edit my answer to explain in more detail please check it. Just copy from here and past in your code and remove code you are using to round the view. And please me know if any issue.