# Programmatically Setting Corner Radius for UIButtons in Landscape and Portrait Mode for All iPhone and iPad Devices

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cornerradius

The app I am working on is a near replicate of *Apple's default iPhone calculator app*.

I am having a hard time in keeping the corner radius set for both the basic operator buttons in portrait and the basic operator buttons plus additional buttons in landscape mode.

Is specifying the corner radius (by dividing the `UIButton.bounds.height / 2`) in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` the right place?

I need the buttons left and right side to stay round on all device rotations. I am not concerned with the top and bottom of the buttons being round.

Thank you all for your consideration in helping me figure out this issue. I am not looking for a direct answer, but if you all could maybe point me to some topics to look into that would be a huge help. I have also tried setting the corner radius in `viewDidAppear().`

Looking for a programmatic solution using `UIButton.bounds.height.` I believe I am just trying to find the right method to implement the corner radius through

```
   var cornerRadius_forButtons: Double = 0
  if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft{
            cornerRadius_forButtons = Double(tag1_Button.bounds.height / 2.0)
        }
        else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight{
            cornerRadius_forButtons = Double(tag1_Button.bounds.height / 2.0)

        } else {

            cornerRadius_forButtons = Double(tag1_Button.bounds.height / 2.0)

        }
 UIButton.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(cornerRadius_forButtons)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use this method the only thing that is slightly hard is setting the constraints. You will not have to mess with code for the most part.

**1.)** In an image editor make a circle. [Link To Image Editor I Used](https://vectr.com)

[image: Created Circle]

**2.)** Add the operator/number to middle of circle
[image]

**3.)** Make background transparent *(Not needed if background white)*

**4.)** Add the image to your apps Assets Folder

[image]

**5.)** In Xcode set the buttons `image` property to the image you just created.

[image]

**6.)** Create constraints for all of your buttons

**Now it should work on all devices regardless of orientation.**

Comment: Sorry for being vague in my initial question, but I am looking for a programmatic solution as the default bounds of the buttons in landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: Maybe these would help? https://www.appcoda.com/rounded-corners-uiview/         and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587713/how-to-set-imageview-in-circle-like-imagecontacts-in-swift-correctly.   Thats my best guess. Sorry if not what your looking for as I usually use the method I posted.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might be onto something! Just now, I realized its not working only on iPad devices. Kinda odd. All the calculator buttons that are present in landscape view for iPhone display in both the landscape and portrait mode for iPad. The buttons load fine initiially on iPad but they don't update when the device is rotated? I will try to add some pictures of my project. Thank you, Nol.

Comment: Found the issue... left some code in viewDidLoad that claculated the corner radius. That was setting it before viewWillLayoutSubviews could get to it. Updating and calculating the code in viewWillLayoutSubviews is what resolved this issue.

Comment: Glad you could fix it

Answer (score 0):

Issue was on my end. The solution to getting round edges on both the left and ride side of UIButton(s) in portrait and landscape modes for all iOS devices was successfully done by calculating and implementing the corner radius in

```
   var cornerRadius_forButtons: Double = 0

   override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft{

        cornerRadius_forButtons = Double(tag1_Button.bounds.height / 2.0)

    }
      else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight{

        cornerRadius_forButtons = Double(tag1_Button.bounds.height / 2.0)

    } else {

        //PORTRAIT

        cornerRadius_forButtons = Double(tag1_Button.bounds.height / 2.0)

    }

    tag1_Button.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(cornerRadius_forButtons)

     }
```